# "Open with.." in Explorer does not start my application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I'm writing a Windows Forms application for reading and writing to my own file type. The program is made using Visual Studio 2015, .NET 4.6.

I ran into an issue when I was gonna associate my program with the file type, by right clicking the file, clicking Open With, and finally I checked the option to always open the file extension with this program. The problem is that when I try to start the program by double-clicking the **file**, nothing happens. The program doesn't show up on the screen.

I opened up task manager to see if it starts, and I noticed that it actually does start for a short while but runs in the background, then closes.

At first I thought it was an issue with my project, so I created a new Windows Forms project, changing not a single project setting, and associated the file type to that instead, and still I have the same problem. I also tried the same application on a different computer and I have the same problem.

Note that I can actually open the program normally, that is by double clicking the .exe in the Windows Explorer, and also run it through Visual Studio.

This is what I have in Program.cs and Form1.cs in the test project I created, which also fails to start through association:

**Program.cs**

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(args.Length == 0 ? new Form1(string.Empty) : new Form1(args[0]));
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1(string path)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Nothing here gets called.            

        if (path != string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File path found!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No file path found.");
        }
    }
}
```

This is new to me because I have associated file types to my programs before, and had no issues. It was however with earlier versions of Visual Studio, so I'm not sure if that has something to do with it.

It has been confusing me for a couple of days now so I'm coming here for help and hopefully help others who have the same problem.

I tried it on both Windows 7 x64 and Windows 10 x86.

I appreciate any thoughts on this.

Comment: Code works as posted.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your issue either :( Works as posted. Do you have any unmentioned circumstances? Such as running in a VM? Attempting to start an executable over a UNC path? Anything external that might help account for the behavior.

Comment: @KevinBurdett I wish it was something like that, but no I'm not using a VM, just running it normally on my main and only OS in the computer. I just think it's strange how I get the same problem on both of my computers, even after rebuilding the project. Are you using the same version of VS and .NET as I am? Cause if not I'm going out on a limb and assuming it has something to do with it, although it feels unlikely.

Comment: @WilliamEvenius: I am running in a Parallels VM on my Macbook Pro. Windows 10 x64, VS 2015 Pro 14.0.24720.00 Update 1, .NET 4.6.01038.

Comment: @KevinBurdett Ah same .NET version. I am however using Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.23107.0. I'm gonna look further into this, will report back if I find anything, thank you by the way.

Comment: I would modify the program to log the command line arguments (maybe to a flat file) before trying to do anything. You might be surprised by what you see. If the file path contains spaces, for example, you might only get a portion of it, unless you modify the file association to add quotes around `%1`.

Answer (score 1):

Association of app with file extension(works well with windows 10):

```
String App_Exe = "MyApp.exe";
String App_Path = "%localappdata%";
SetAssociation_User("myExt", App_Path + App_Exe, App_Exe);

public static void SetAssociation_User(string Extension, string OpenWith, string ExecutableName){
    try {
        using (RegistryKey User_Classes = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\", true))
        using (RegistryKey User_Ext = User_Classes.CreateSubKey("." + Extension))
        using (RegistryKey User_AutoFile = User_Classes.CreateSubKey(Extension + "_auto_file"))
        using (RegistryKey User_AutoFile_Command = User_AutoFile.CreateSubKey("shell").CreateSubKey("open").CreateSubKey("command"))
        using (RegistryKey ApplicationAssociationToasts = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\ApplicationAssociationToasts\\", true))
        using (RegistryKey User_Classes_Applications = User_Classes.CreateSubKey("Applications"))
        using (RegistryKey User_Classes_Applications_Exe = User_Classes_Applications.CreateSubKey(ExecutableName))
        using (RegistryKey User_Application_Command = User_Classes_Applications_Exe.CreateSubKey("shell").CreateSubKey("open").CreateSubKey("command"))
        using (RegistryKey User_Explorer = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\FileExts\\." + Extension))
        using (RegistryKey User_Choice = User_Explorer.OpenSubKey("UserChoice")){
              User_Ext.SetValue("", Extension + "_auto_file", RegistryValueKind.String);
              User_Classes.SetValue("", Extension + "_auto_file", RegistryValueKind.String);
              User_Classes.CreateSubKey(Extension + "_auto_file");
              User_AutoFile_Command.SetValue("", "\"" + OpenWith + "\"" + " \"%1\"");
              ApplicationAssociationToasts.SetValue(Extension + "_auto_file_." + Extension, 0);
              ApplicationAssociationToasts.SetValue(@"Applications\" + ExecutableName + "_." + Extension, 0);
              User_Application_Command.SetValue("", "\"" + OpenWith + "\"" + " \"%1\"");
              User_Explorer.CreateSubKey("OpenWithList").SetValue("a", ExecutableName);
              User_Explorer.CreateSubKey("OpenWithProgids").SetValue(Extension + "_auto_file", "0");

              if (User_Choice != null) User_Explorer.DeleteSubKey("UserChoice");
                  User_Explorer.CreateSubKey("UserChoice").SetValue("ProgId", @"Applications\" + ExecutableName);
              }

              SHChangeNotify(0x08000000, 0x0000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Your code here
        }
  }

  [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern void SHChangeNotify(uint wEventId, uint uFlags, IntPtr dwItem1, IntPtr dwItem2);
```

---

What about your code, generally it must work as is, but will be better to update the code by the following way:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

---

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // The first element in the array contains the file name of the executing program. 
        // If the file name is not available, the first element is equal to String.Empty. 
        // The remaining elements contain any additional tokens entered on the command line. 
        var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];
        var path = (args.Count == 1) ? args[0] : args[1];

        if (path == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No file path found.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File path found!");
        }
    }
}
```

didn't try the code because of I have no access to VS right now. So there may be some code mistakes.